# Weblogic - Testing SOAP Web Service With Test Client

Tags: web-services, web-deployment, jdeveloper, ear, weblogic-10.x

I have created a `PL/SQL SOAP Web Service` using the `Web Services Wizard` in `JDeveloper 11g`. I am able to successfully deploy it on the `Integrated Weblogic Server`. After which I am able to launch the `Weblogic Test Client` in a browser.

I then **deployed the web service to an EAR** using the Deployment Profile , created for the web service application **(using Jdeveloper)**. **Used this EAR to deploy the service to a remote dev weblogic managed server** (NOTE: I am using `Weblogic 10.3.5.0`).

Deployment was successful and I was able to start the application too. The state of the deployment is "Active" and the is health "OK" . **I am able to see the dynamic WSDL for the my web service too.**

Here is where i am having issues. **I am unable to test the web service by using the Weblogic Test Client. I am getting the `404 Not Found` error when i click on the web service test point.**

Has anyone had the same issue with launching the test client ?

Appreciate your comments / suggestions !!!

[image: Deployment Details][image: Error on clicking the web services end point]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make yourself a test soap script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['request'])){
    $XML = $_POST['request'];
    $URL = $_POST['url'];
    $ch = curl_init("$URL");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$XML);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>

<form method="post" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <input name='url' type="text" placeholder="URL here" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['url'])) echo $_POST['url']; ?>" style="height: 10%; width:90%">
    <button style="width: 10%; height: 10%;">LOAD SOAP</button><br />
    <textarea style="width: 50%; height:90%;" placeholder='REQUEST HERE' name="request"><?php if(isset($_POST['request'])) echo $_POST['request']; ?></textarea>
    <textarea placeholder="RESPONSE HERE" disabled="true" style="width: 50%; height:90%;"><?php if(isset($result)) echo $result; ?></textarea>
</form>
```